# How to make an image change when clicking on a button

Tags: android

I am displaying image on when clicking on a `Button` using interface but the image `ic_launcher.png` does not show up on the `Button` after some time the `image_all.png` is only shown.

- How should I show my first image for some time using sleep and then show image2?
- Should I show both the images on the same button but with time delay.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
try{
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
} catch(Exception e){

}
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images_all);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Thread.sleep(1000);` you're actually "stopping" the UI thread, because you're calling `sleep(1000);` on the UI thread. This causes your application to halt completely for 1 second in your case.

So this isn't such a good idea :-)

Instead you should use something like a `Handler` for instance. A `Handler` can be called with a specified delay, so that the action will first be performed after the specified delay. And most importantly, the `Handler` doesn't "block" the UI thread, as the `Thread.sleep(1000);` does.

So using a `Handler` your code, could look something like this instead:

```
button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
uiHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images_all);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Notice the `1000` in the end of `postDelayed()` which tells the `Handler` to post this "message" after 1000 milliseconds instead of immediately.

On a side-note: It's not good practice to "eat" the `Exceptions` like you do in your `try-catch`.

Comment: You and I came up with the exact same answer at about the exact same time. :-)

Comment: @JessieA.Morris ;-) It's actually amazing, since the question has been open for more than 10 hours straight without any "action" :-)

Comment: I know, I noticed the same thing. 10 hours with 11 views. I don't know how this wasn't answered sooner. :-P

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to see the `R.drawable.ic_launcher` change occur. My thoughts about this are around how you're doing the `Thread.sleep()`. Android isn't fond of performing blocking tasks (such as Thread.sleep) in the UI Thread. When you call the setBackgroundResource and then sleep, the thread that would update the UI is sleeping and cannot perform the update. This is how I would do it instead:

```
    button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images_all);
        }
    }, 1000);
```